# (K)Ubuntu 18.10 boots into emergency mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu, 18.10, fsck

I finally switched from Wndows to Kubuntu because it seemed pretty stable, compared to, KDE Neon, Manjaro and Netrunner, Kaos, and Chakra (yes, I wanted the KDE desktop by default as you can see), for 3-4 days everything worked fine, (except some problems with the NVIDIA drivers that I managed to fix on my own). Recently every time that I boot my machine normally enters in this mode. I managed to make a workaround booting to ubuntu's recovery mode, selecting *any* option (tried with 3), and resuming the boot.

After that everything works fine, and I am writing this on Kubuntu even.

I made my own research and I already tried the following:

- fsck on LiveCD (No errors, forced it (with -y -f) to repair, clean)
- Tried to read the journalctr (Didn't see anything in special, It's
  also pretty hard to read)
- Switched kernels
- fsck on recovery (same as above)
- Update grub from inside the working environment, recovery and
  emergency mode

Some thing that I noticed, is using this order  "journalctl -p err -b" shows me (clearly) some errors:

- Polymouth couldn't boot
- And the fsck on boot, fails with code 4

I only used the command stated above once. Some "fishy things" that I done before that could be the cause:

- Used grub customizer to edit the timeout time
- Made a "sdd" folder on my sdd that is / , and changed the ownership because I needed the speed. (/home is on a different hard drive)
- While the Nvidia installation I rolled back with timeshift a long number of times after breaking.
- I edited (and restored the backup after all of this) of fstab trying to optimize the sdd load.
- Installed in a completely different partition on the sdd Windows 7 in case of I needed some program and Wine fails me (not at the moment) (the error showed some days after, used grub customizer again to add to grub Windows 7)

Thanks for reading.

Edit: After some testing, after booting in the recovery mode way depicted above, I get stuck on a black screen if I try to boot at the normal way, I had to reboot the computer, to get the next time the same error on normal boot.